# Storing hierarchical data to Core Data in 1 pass?

Tags: ios, core-data

When loading data into Core Data, my child objects aren't getting the parent ID set. This is all generated as I walk through an xml document using TBXML. (code heavily paraphrased for brevity)

```
a = NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"A"
set various a attributes
if a.Type isEqualToString:@"TypeA"
    b_set = NSMutableSet new
    for each child element of a
        b = NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"B"
        set various b attributes
        b.a = a
        b_set addObject:b
    next
    a.bs = b_set
end
blah blah blah
```

When all is said and done, all the a's and b's, and all their atttributes are correctly persisted to SQLite, except that all the b's have null for their a (the parent) attribute.

Do I have to rework this to write the a before creating the b's so they have a real objectID to reference?

Comment: When are you performing a save?

Comment: Does each a have the correct set of b's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse relationships are updated as part of `-processPendingChanges`. That will get called as part of `-save:`. If you need to, you can call it directly. CoreData will not update the reverse relationships immediately since it's costly.